# assertEquals compares objects id and not the content of the object?

Tags: junit, junit4

I wanted to test my `insert` method. The `insert` method simply adds the object to the list. However, when I used `assertEquals`, it seemed to be comparing objects and not the content of the objects.

Is there a way to compare the elements of the user defined objects that is stored in an ArrayList?

```
@Test
public void testInsert() {
    // Method answer
    Interval newInterval = new Interval(1, 20);
    ArrayList<Interval> emptyInterval = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    ArrayList<Interval> returnedAnswer = Solution.insert(emptyInterval, newInterval);

    // Expected answer
    ArrayList<Interval> expected = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    //expected.add(newInterval); // This will pass
    expected.add(new Interval(1, 20)); // This will fail

    assertEquals(expected, returnedAnswer);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assertEquals` tests equality of objects by calling their `equals` method. This means that the objects must have a sufficient implementation of that method. It looks like `Interval` does not have it. Therefore you have to implement `Interval.equals(Object)`.

You can use [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) matchers if you don't want to override `equals`. But you need the `reflectEquals` matcher of [NitorCreations matcher](https://github.com/NitorCreations/matchers) library, too.

```
assertThat(returnedAnswer, contains(
  reflectsEquals(new Interval(1, 20))));
```

Maybe [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) provides a similar assert, but you have to look for yourself, because I'm rarely using AssertJ.

Comment: Great! Implemented my own `Interval.equals(Object)` and worked like a charm. However, are there other ways of doing it? because if I have many user-defined classes, that'd be really cumbersome to override the `euqals` for every class.

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan, for the help. I have not used Hamcrest before, new to JUnit as well. I will have to look more into that. For now, I think I will just stick with overriding `equals`.